# C++, Calling delete on Base Class results in?

Tags: c++, inheritance

i have two questions related to the following code in C++:

```
class Base
{
public:
    virtual bool deleteMe()
    { 
        delete this;
        return true;
    }
};

class Derived: public Base
{
public:
    void setBCO(const BigCustomObject& t_BCO)
    { m_BCO=t_BCO;}

    BigCustomObject m_BCO;
};


int main()
{
    Derived *pDerived = new Derived();

    //insertint the "BigCustomObject" by new or local copy makes no difference, or?
    //Because the "setBCO(){m_BCO=t_BCO;}" calls the copy operator anyway, or?
    pDerived->setBCO( ... );

    bool checkDel = pDerived->deleteMe();

    //bool checkDel = ((Base*)pDerived)->deleteMe(); //Does this make any difference?
    std::cout<<checkDel;
}
```

1.) How is it possible that the deleteMe() Function returns a value after it deleted its own object???

2.) What happens to the "BigCustomObject" in the derived Object, when only the Base Object is deleted?

Thank you.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

1. The object for which code executes is just used as the `this` pointer (and implicit container for unqualified member names). It doesn't have any relation to the executable code itself, so execution can continue just fine. If `deleteMe()` tried to access any data members of `this` after the deletion, however, it woud be in trouble.
2. In your case, it's probably leaked. Technically speaking, the code has Undefined Behaviour, so anything can happen. The reason is that `Base` doesn't have a virtual destructor, so deleting a derived object though a pointer to a base class is undefined. If `Base` had a virtual destructor, however, it would work just fine - the destructor of `Derived` would be called (through virtual dispatch), which in turn would call the destructor of `BigCustomObject` to destroy `m_BCO` and then call the destructor of `Base`.

Comment: Thought the virtual destructor for Base makes only sense if the Derived Class had any members allocated with new, which than have to be deleted in the destructor of Derived.

Comment: @user1911091 Not really. Going by the standard, deleting a derived class through a pointer to base without a virtual dtor is UB, period. In practice, it's possible that some implementations will behave "correctly," but it's extremely fragile. For example, optimisers are allowed to assume UB does not happen.

Answer (score 3):

1) The code doesn't self-destruct just because the memory for the object does. It just means that data referred to by member variables will be invalid.

2) I would guess the BigCustomObject doesn't get correctly destructed since Base does not have a virtual destructor.

Answer (score 0):

First you have no virtual destructor for the base class so when you call `delete this` (where this is `Base`) BigCustomObject from `Derived` class doesn't get destroyed.
Also the execution of the function is still ok since you don't use the object (this) any longer.

The answer to your question is in the comments of the example code:

```
class Base
{
public:
    virtual bool deleteMe()
    { 
        this->some_member = 0;//valid
        delete this; 

        //from here on everything you do you can is ok if you don't touch `this`

        //for example:
        //this->some_member = 0;//this is not safe since the object this is already destroyed

        return true;
    }
    virtual ~Base()
    {
        //virtual means that Dirived class has it's destructor called before this one does
    }

    int some_member;//member added to illustrate the lifetimeo of base class
};
```